# Differential equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, functional-equations

Consider $u = u(\phi,\psi)$ where $\phi = \phi(x)$ and $\psi =\psi(x)$ are both analytic function. The following equation
$$\partial_x u - u\partial_x (\phi-\psi)=0$$
has a trivial solution  $u(\phi,\psi) = c\,e^{\phi-\psi}$, where $c$ is a constant. Note that $u(\phi,\psi) = c\,e^{\phi-\psi}$ solves the above equation for whatever function of $x$ $\phi$ and $\psi$ is.

This equation doesn't seems to be an ordinary differential equation because none function of $x$ whas found. Is it a functional differential equation?

I'm wondering to solve the following equation

$$\partial_x v - v\partial_x(\phi+\psi) = e^{\phi-\psi} - e^{-\phi+\psi}$$

where the aim is to find $v = v(\phi,\psi)$.

How do I call (or classify) differential equations where the aim is to find a function that depends of another function like those shown above?

PS: Such equations appears in the context of algebraic description of Backlund Transformation via gauge transformation.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want a solution $y(x)$ of the ODE 
$$y'(x)-y(x)\big(\phi'(x)-\psi'(x)\big)= e^{\phi(x)-\psi(x)}-e^{-\phi(x)+\psi(x)},$$
AND you want this solution to be of the form $y(x):=v(\phi(x),\psi(x))$ for some $2$-variable function $v(t,s)$. Is this the problem?

Comment: If so, it seems the factorization is quite a disjoint problem from the linear ODE. The latter can be easily integrated and has a general solution of some form $y(x)=Y(x,\phi(x),\psi(x),C)$. So I'd say all you need is to write $x$ in terms of the given functins $\phi$ and $\psi$ as $$x=w(\phi(x),\psi(x)),$$ for some $2$-variable function $w$, and then define 
$$v(t,s):= Y(w(t,s),t,s,C)$$
so that $v(\phi(x), \psi(x))=y(x)$